# What is the physical meaning of 'infinite variance'?

Tags: bayesian, variance

I am currently reading the book: [Bayesian Logical Data Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=idkLAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=global%20likelihood%20for%20uniform%20prior%20case&source=bl&ots=nrze5ulEdo&sig=VVeJK_ko3ZgmTYPGX-tTQfjUw0M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJiLH-9I7LAhVpr4MKHVXwADIQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=global%20likelihood%20for%20uniform%20prior%20case&f=false). In chapter 5 it is mentioned like below:

*"What happens to the average of samples drawn from a distribution which has an infinite variance? In this case, the
error bar for the sample mean does not decrease with increasing n''.*

My query is, what would be an ideal example of infinite variance?

Answer (score 1):

At first I would also say Cauchy. But I think the objection is that mean of Cauchy distribution is undefined and therefore its variance is technically also undefined.

But another example could [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution), which is interesting because based on initial parameters it could have finite both mean and variance, only mean or both mean and variance are infinite.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is the standard Cauchy distribution $\dfrac{dx/\pi}{1+x^2}$.

If the variance of a probability distribution is characterized as $\frac 1 2 \operatorname{E}\left(( X_1 - X_2)^2\right)$, where $X_1,X_2$ is an i.i.d. sample, then this has infinite variance.

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent random variables with this distribution then $\bar X_n= \dfrac{X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \vphantom{\dfrac\int\int}$ also has this same distribution rather than one that is more concentrated near the center.

Comment: Is there a reason why this was down-voted? $\qquad$

Comment: I think Cauchy is perfect example,  even thought I prefer its description   using [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

Comment: yes there is a reason: "standard Cauchy distribution" does not have an infinite variance.

Comment: Cauchy doesn't have a mean, so it's bad example of "sample mean not converging to true mean in $L^2$ when variance is infinite".

Comment: If one characterizes the variance as $\dfrac 1 2 \operatorname{E}\left(( X_1 - X_2)^2\right)$ where $X_1,X_2$ is an i.i.d. sample, then the Cauchy distribution has infinite variance. $\qquad$

Comment: That's a non-sequitur. The problem is absence of the *mean* itself - which makes "$\bar X_n\to \mu_X$" (as well as the whole concept error bars) meaningless/irrelevant.

Comment: @A.S. : "Non sequitur" means drawing a conclusion unrelated to the evidence.  Is that what you're claiming this is? $\qquad$

Comment: You present a definition of variance that allows us to define variance for distributions without a mean and imply that it makes your example relevant to the OP. It doesn't. You need a distribution with a finite mean as an example.